# Can't stomach pumpkin flavor. How can I make it edible?

Tags: pumpkin

Never been able to eat pumpkin really, I think it's a combination of it being mushy (texture) and sweet (but not in a good way sweet). My mom mostly used to make it without drying it out much, it was still pretty moist. Didn't like pumpkin in cakes either.

Is there a way to balance those flavors and textures and make it work?

I only recently started to experiment with various types of winter squash. Tried acorn yesterday and it was pretty good, mainly when sliced thinly and roasted (savory). I'm going to try the same with pumpkin (sliced thinly) but not raising my hopes too high. I wonder how I could incorporate acids in there and if they would help.

Comment: This question might be too opinion-based for this venue. It is certainly true that pumpkin can be quite mushy and sweet. But there are many different savory pumpkin recipes; asking for ones that "work" is going to be quite subjective.

Comment: Acorn or Hubbard squash are better choices for pumpkin pie than pumpkin. *You* get to decide how much sweet stuff you add to it. Cut back.

Comment: If you don't like it, why force the issue?  There are plenty of squashes to try, and they vary significantly.

Comment: Heck, there are many varieties of pumpkin to try, and some of them have quite different taste/texture.

Comment: How do you feel about pumpkin pie?

Answer (score 2):

The pumpkins I grow only go mushy if cooked in water or microwaved , so I suggest cooking them without water, but with oil.

Diced fairly small and fried in hot oil with spices is a good way to start a tagine, curry, or chilli. You want even browning before adding liquid. The chilli I make then gets cooked slowly, and the pieces might go a bit soft for you, but any tasty recipe that fries pumpkin then just warms through sauce ingredients is worth a try.

Roasting is also a possibility, well seasoned, but leave it too long and you might not like it again. I'd be tempted to try a similar seasoning to what I use on sweet potato wedges - smoked paprika, cumin, herbs, black pepper and fine polenta to give a bit of crispness on the surface.

Comment: Add some balsamic vinegar to the pumpkin when roasting, or as a dressing afterward - delicious.

Comment: @bob1 hopefully that's good way sweet to the OP. It's a good idea, though I was going for fully savoury